# Git 'Revert currently in progress': how to explore differences?

Tags: git

## Background

Somehow I ran into a revert only partially completed:

```
❯ git status
On branch feature/myfeature
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/myfeature'.

Revert currently in progress.
  (run "git revert --continue" to continue)
  (use "git revert --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ../demo/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I am not sure what is different in this partially reverted commit versus `HEAD`.  I don't see any differences on my IDE (VS Code).  Also, as shown above, the `git status` does not show me what files are different or what files are in this partial revert.

I also don't even know what commits are being reverted.

## Question

- What commands are available to explore what is involved in the revert?  I'd really like to know all, but specifically:

  - What commit(s) are being reverted?
  - What files are impacted by the revert?
  - Can I `git diff` those files to see what the revert will impact?

    - If not, is there a way to git diff two different commits, but only look at what is different with those two, not including everything in between?  (`git revert` only reverts that specific commit, not everything in between.  `git reset` also changes everything in between.)

---

I read the official git reference and did some Google searches, but I could not find anything helping me to understand how to *explore* what the revert is doing.

---

### Update

My git release info:

```
❯ git --version
git version 2.31.1
```

My `.git` folder:

```
❯ \ls -1       
COMMIT_EDITMSG
FETCH_HEAD
HEAD
ORIG_HEAD
config
description
hooks
index
info
logs
objects
packed-refs
refs
sequencer
```

Comment: There is *some* information encoded in the various revert-to-do files, but there's no easy way to view it.

Comment: Where could I find those files, @torek ?

Comment: They've moved around in different Git releases. I'd have to run a `git revert` to find where they go now. They will be per-work-tree with the default worktree using `.git/<path>` and added work-trees using `.git/worktrees/<work-tree>/<path>`. Ideally, `git status` would read them and tell you about the ongoing rebase, and I think a *modern* Git actually *does* do that, which makes me suspect you have an older Git release. (But I haven't checked.)

Comment: Thank you, @torek, but my Git release is quite new.  I have updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `worktrees`.  I have never seen that path in the `.git` folder before.  I have provided what my `.git` folder looks like (at the top level, at least).

Comment: You get worktrees with `git worktree add`. Your revert data will be in the `sequencer` directory.

Comment: OK, thanks, @torek !